# Kever of a Tzaddik "bechinas" Eretz Yisrael

Tags: eretz-yisrael, cemetery-grave, tzaddikim

I've heard many say before (usually in connection to Reb Nachman Breslover) that the kever (burial spot) of a tzaddik found outside of Eretz Yisrael is "bechinas" (or the likeness) of Eretz Yisrael. What is the source for this? Who said it?

Answer (score 2):

[Likutei Moharan II:109](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A8%22%D7%9F_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%A7%D7%98) states:

סִפֵּר עִמִּי מֵעִנְיַן קֶבֶר הַבַּעַל שֵׁם טוֹב, זֵכֶר צַדִּיק וְקָדוֹשׁ לִבְרָכָה שֶׁטּוֹב מְאֹד לִהְיוֹת שָׁם עַל קִבְרוֹ וְאָמַר כִּי "צַדִּיקִים יִירְשׁוּ אָרֶץ" (תְּהִלִּים ל"ז) הַיְנוּ שֶׁהַצַּדִּיקִים אֲמִתִּיִּים יוֹרְשִׁים אֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁזּוֹכִין שֶׁמְּקוֹם גְּנִיזָתָם הוּא קָדוֹשׁ בִּקְדֻשַּׁת אֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל מַמָּשׁ וְאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל הוּא תִּקּוּן גָּדוֹל לִפְגַם הַבְּרִית.

Translation:
He told me, in relation to the Ba`al Shem Tov's grave, ztzuk"l,
that it is a very great thing to be at his gravesite.
And he said: because "Tzaddikim yiyreshu aretz/The righteous shall inherit the Land" (Ps. 37).
That is to say, True Tzaddikim inherit the Land of Yisrael,
as they merit that their burial place be sanctified with the holiness of the Land of Yisrael, tangibly.
And the Land of Yisrael is a great remedy for repair of the Covenant.

Comment: There is no makor earlier than Reb Nachman himself that the burial places of tzaddikim are like Eretz Yisrael? ... The Sdei Chemed I am familiar with and I believe he is the "earliest makor" for such a heter to leave Eretz Yisrael, but let's save that discussion for a different time.

Comment: I looked in this print of the sefer: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46121&st=&pgnum=1&hilite= and I did not find it in Torah 108 ???

Comment: "The Rebbe quoted the possuk" which Rebbe?

Comment: Sdei Chemed both postdates R. Nachman of Breslov, and is irrelevant. It is permitted to leave the land for many things. E.g. livelihood. That is not to say that livelihood and the land are the same.

Comment: @mevaqesh It seems to me from reading the Shaar Breslav that the "Rebbe" quoted was Reb Nachman himself.

Comment: Also Ps. 16:3: "לִקְדוֹשִׁים, אֲשֶׁר-בָּאָרֶץ הֵמָּה" That is, by the holy ones who are [buried in what is now an aspect of the] Land [of Yisrael] though it was in the foreigners' [Land].